# Ошибка установки Nuget entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget

При попытке установки пакета Entity Framework возникает ошибка.

Не удалось извлечь результаты из канала V2 по адресу "https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/FindPackagesById()?id='EntityFramework'&semVerLevel=2.0.0" со следующим сообщением: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
  Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
Прошло времени: 00:00:01.1761515
========== Готово ==========

[Package source] Веб-канал V2 в "https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='net461'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0" вернул непредвиденный код состояния: "404 Not Found".

Переустановка студии не помогла.. Установка через консоль диспетчера пакетов выдаёт тоже ошибку. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему:(

Comment: Вы поди не слышали, сколько по всему миру недоступно сервисов после начала блокировки телеграмма Роскомнадзором? Наверняка дело именно в этом.

Comment: Так и есть, слышал о недоступности именно nuget из за блокировок.

Comment: Попробуйте источником https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. Вчера нагет колбасило, сегодня вроде отпустило

Comment: @Zufir , а можно поподробнее? Я не очень опытный программист:) Как мне поступить с данным json ответом?

Comment: @cancoder , меню Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager Settings. Откроется окно настроек, дальше пунке Package sources, выбираете Nuget.org (скорее всего он у Вас единственный), в поле Source вставляете эту ссылку

Comment: @Zufir ,  пишет: "указан недопустимый источник"

Comment: А версия студии?

Comment: @Zufir 15.6.6 (VS 2017)

Comment: @cancoder http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/04/18/0004/1311/320799/99/adc4d03b5d.png

Comment: @Zufir СПАСИБО!!!!!!